# Migrate service and IP address from one pc to another, so that the other pc takes the place of the first but also retains its original IP

Tags: ip, migration

I have a Cubieboard on 192.168.20.10 which serves as a DNS-server.

I also have now a new, somewhat bigger PC on 192.168.20.20 which is now hosting some services, but not DNS. I want to move the DNS server from x.x.x.10 to x.x.x.20, but have several IoT devices with hardcoded static settings.

Can I "copy" the DNS server to x.x.x.20 (would be trivial) and also move/assign the IP address x.x.x.10 to the x.x.x.20 board, so that it has has both IPs on the same interface, and power off the Cubieboard forever?

I'd also need all requests from the new PC still leave via the x.x.x.20 IP, except for the DNS replies, since they are made to the x.x.x.10 IP

A downtime of about 1 minute is acceptable.

Using DHCP on every device is not an option, also because Android 5.x has a bug in its DHCP client which causes disconnects on every DHCP refresh, and I refresh often.

Comment: You can have several IPv4 addresses on the same interface, but there are some issues (e.g., which source address should be used for outgoing packets?). Hopefully, the DNS server can be configured to bind on x.x.x.10, so the whole thing *may* work (but I've never tried anything like this myself). As it's a home network, in your place I'd just try it, test thoroughly, and switch back if there are gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two devices on the same network segment using the same IP address; this is the very definition of an IP Address conflict.

You *can* have DNS running on both hosts, and transition the hosts to use the new DNS server or, probably more wisely, transition the IoT devices to use DHCP with MAC Address reservations to give them static DHCP IP assignments and DNS Server settings.  You can then use DHCP to cut DNS service from one host to the other seamlessly.

If the old device is going to be shut down and/or repurposed *with a new IP Address*, most devices (presumably including the new one) are capable of adding virtual interfaces (e. g. `eth0` can also drive `eth0:0` and `eth0:1` each with their own IP stack).  So once the old device is removed, you can add a new virtual interface on the old IP address, and have your DNS server listen on all (non-public-facing) interfaces.

Comment: "You cannot have two devices on the same network segment using the same IP address; this is the very definition of an IP Address conflict." That is why I mention that I'm shutting down the Cubieboard forever. A downtime of 1 minute of the DNS server is something the entire network can tolerate. Like when the Cubieboard has to be rebooted. --- I'm aware of DHCP, but some devices had issues with my custom DHCP server so I did set them to static.